# Variable defined in constructor not available in class methods

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I am trying to access the name defined in the constructor via a method, but it is returning undefined. Here is the simple code:

```js
class Person {
  constructor(){
     let name = 'Tom';
    }
  logName(){
     console.log(this.name);
   }
}

let x = new Person();
x.logName();
```

Comment: Assign to `this.name` in order to assign it as a property of the instantiated object - else it's just a free variable, with all the usual scoping rules

Comment: `let this.name = 'Tom'` returns error in constructor. Why?

Comment: @yuvrajprogrammer Just `this.name = "Tom";`. `this.name` is not an identifier.

Comment: Don't use `var` or `let` to define properties

Comment: Thank you all for the explanation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to define the name as a property of the object. In your case `this.name`

```js
class Person {
  constructor(){
     this.name = 'Tom';
    }
  logName(){
     console.log(this.name);
   }
}

let x = new Person();
x.logName();
```

In your code, you've defined the variable `name` inside the constructor. It remains in there but doesn't escape.